# How to catch events of ion-view?

Tags: ionic-framework

According to the [official doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/), ion-view will emit its life-cycle events to help us control its logic.

But how can I catch these events?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can attach the events with the `$scope` in the relevant controller.

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function (viewInfo, state) {
        console.log('CTRL - $ionicView.loaded', viewInfo, state);
    });
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.unloaded', function (viewInfo, state) {
        console.log('CTRL - $ionicView.unloaded', viewInfo, state);
    });
});
```